# Cubemap lookup in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

When doing a lookup in a cubemap in GLSL 1.50 (or later) using the function

```
gvec4 texture(  gsamplerCube    sampler,
    vec3    P,
    [float      bias]);
```

must the P be a unit-length vector - or would any non-zero vec3 be a valid input?

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Comment: @RobertRouhani: That's not helpful. Driver bugs could allow it to "work" even though it might be forbidden in the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not have to be normalized.